# Qt Webkit output is not same like mozilla/IE for some website

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebkit

I am using QWebKit class to display the webpages but for some websites output is not coming same as other standard browsers.

For example the below mention site contain one flash video at the right side, if you click on the full screen of this flash video , then the options on the flash player that is present at the bottom right corner are not same as other browsers.

http://www.hosmatnet.com/

Link for the snapshot of the differences.
https://picasaweb.google.com/103939036468452830901/Qt#5767128130858501410

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of different reasons, different versions of Flash, whether the Flash library is running (it might be defaulting to the HTML player on YouTube), and the biggy is it's entirely based on what browser agent your displaying. Some won't track it, others will to tailor the experience.

Comment: I found that even safari browser also displays the same like Qt browser. All are webkit based browsers.